# Is it possible to get shape of a TFdataset similar to a pandas.shape()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I execute this command I get:

```
print(df.shape)
(172717, 1521)
```

but if I convert the dataframe to a `tf` dataframe:

```
  df_numpy = df.to_numpy()
  df_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(df_numpy)
```

I can see rows but not columns:

```
len(list(df_tensor))
172717
```

I have a ML model and I want the input layer to be generated dynamically so I need the columns to add them together to create the input shape:

```
input_shape = (df.shape[1] + df2.shape[1] + df3.shape[1]))
```

obviously, this works with pandas but it doesn't work with `tf` datasets because I cannot get the shape.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ragged tensors (`tf.RaggedTensor`), are tensors with **non-uniform** shapes, thus using `.get_shape()`, you only get `[num_of_rows, None]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Roll': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Mark': [95, 96, 98, 100, 95],
                   })

tf_df = tf.ragged.constant(df.to_numpy())
tf_df.get_shape()
TensorShape([5, None])
```

However, here are some of the ways to get full shape info

```
tf_df.to_sparse().shape
(5, 2)

tf_df.to_tensor().shape
(5, 2)

np.array(tf_df.to_list()).shape
(5, 2)
```